# Include number and date in Apache log file names

Tags: apache, filenames, apache-log-files

I'm trying to figure out how to include the current date and the IP number of the current host inside the Apache log file names, but I fail how to see how I can do that. Part of that has to do with the fact that I don't understand the log rotation mechanism that seems to be enabled by default. Haven't been able to find any documentation on why I have `access.1.log`, `access.xxx.gz.log` files.

(I mean, I *do* understand that it is log rotation, but I *don't* see how I can influence it. I also understand I could pipe log output through some sort of command to include the current IP number in the file name, but I would assume I would lose my log rotation that way. Basically I want the current mechanism, but then include the IP number in the name, and a date rather than a number.)

Comment: I have been digging a little further now. It turns out that the different files with a number appended at the end are generated by some daily rotation scheme, but they are getting created when you restart the server. If you restart the server, the numbers of the existing files will be bumped by one, the current file will be written to access.2.gz.log and the new file will be written to access.1.log.

Comment: Also in order to have real log rotation (based on a daily rotation scheme) you need to use the `CustomLog` directive and pipe the log file through `rotatelogs` (Apache), `cronolog` or `vlogger`. I don't know about the first case, but neither `cronolog` nor `vlogger` gzip files upon rotation. The FAQ of `cronolog` says you better use `cron` for that instead.

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for two things: the [logrotate](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/logrotate8.html) manual and a solution for *parsing* your log files (there are many [free analytics solutions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Free_web_analytics_software) which work for Apache)

Answer (score 2):

This is how log rotation is handled on my Apache server.

```
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common
CustomLog "|/usr/local/sbin/cronolog --american /usr/local/apache2/logs/access_log.%Y%m%d" common
```

[Cronolog](http://cronolog.org/usage.html) creates a daily log file named something like `access_log.20120213`.  I then have a cron job set to move old logs into a subdirectory, gzip logs files older than a week and clean out anything older than one year.